# Buck/Boost converter TPS63070RNMT is not working properly

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter, inductor, texas-instruments, buck-boost

I am working on a Buck/Boost converter design which is based on Buck/Boost converter [TPS63070RNMT](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps63070.pdf). Below is the schematic design. All the selected components are as per the Section 9 of the datasheet.
[image]

U6 is powered by either USB (5V) or a rechargeable battery (2.8V-4.2V) as shown in the Schematic below. Expected Output is +3.3V/2A.
[image]

USB connection is given priority in the design. If both USB & battery are connected to the board, PCB will be powered on by USB while battery gets charged.

The issue I am facing upon powering up is U6 not working as expected. Output is approx 1.2V and there is a lot of humming sound coming out of inductor. U6 is getting heat up very quickly. It is also affecting Original input waveformsand other sections. For example, USB input = 5V DC is superimposed with square wave. VBATT net on U1 also has some distortion in the form of sawtooth signal.

I am suspecting the inductor saturation issue. Did anyone face similar issue earlier?

Below is the layout of 3.3V supply section. It is as per the recommended layout mentioned in datasheet.[image]
Copper pouring added for VIN, Inductor nets and 3.3V. There is a 3.3V copper plane on Layer 3. On TOP layer, whole section is surrounded by Ground copper.

Need some inputs from the expert.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you take care of the saturation current rating of L3

Comment: @Navaro Yeah. L3 rated saturation current is **14A** which ia way higher than what datasheet recommends. In boost mode, for Iout=2A with minimum Vin=2.8V, Ipeak comes around 2.68A as per formulae mentioned in Page 18 of datasheet. . It is recommended to choose an inductor with a saturation current 20% higher than that value.

Comment: For switching supplies, board layout is important. Please don't keep it secret.

Comment: @CL. I have added the layout picture. Have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue and resolved it.
GND pins of C14 and C15 must be connected directly to PGND pin of U6 (Pad between L1 & L2) on the top layer. It is important to make a good GND star connection, the inductor lines for L1 and L2 nets are not so critical, they can go to the inductor through vias and another layer.